# Android 11 Preview - Facebook Login Not Working

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, facebook-android-sdk, android-11

To cut things to the point.

- I have the Facebook login implemented, pretty much this way: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/
- And it works perfectly fine when compiled with API 29 (Android 10)
- But if I compile it with API 30 (Android 11) and run on Pixel device with Android 11 Preview installed, Facebook login stops working as expected and I keep getting a dialog to log into a Facebook, even though I am logged into the app it self.
- Compiled with API 30 (Android 11) and ran on Android 10 or below works perfectly fine.

I don't have anything from logcat, as there's nothing there connected to this.

Anyone else had this?

Cheers

Comment: How did you fixed the issue? I am also facing same issue now

Answer (score -1):

you only need to replace

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
```

by

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'
```

This solution works for me

You can find my example code in [Github](https://github.com/alexlarraga1/facebook-auth-example)

Comment: With `compileSdkVersion 30` and `targetSdkVersion 30`?

Comment: Yes my test run with this SDK version.  You cand find the example code in https://github.com/alexlarraga1/facebook-auth-example

Comment: Works only on virtual device, does not work with real Pixel 3 nor 4.